# How could I create a custom Id in ABP Framework?

Tags: c#, abp

In ABP Framework we have Entity which has a Id, but if my table has a Id with the name ProductId, how could relate ProductId with Id from Entity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try, create an id with the name you want, but when using repositories you will have to use a repository of type (withoud id in generic repo),

```
IRepository<Something>
```

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/AspNet-Boilerplate-Migration-Guide#injecting-the-repositories

To use that repository your entity must implement IEntity, and you have to configure the mapping to database, your entity should be like this

```
 public class Something: IEntity
 {
     public long SomeId {get; set; }
    
     public object [] GetKeys ()
     {
         return new object [] {SomeId};
     }
 }
```

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Best-Practices/Entity-Framework-Core-Integration#model-mapping

and it should work